# React: fire render after promise completed

Tags: reactjs

Please note,  that I a fetching data from AWS DynamoDB.

```
...
class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          contactList: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var getItemsPromise = db.scan({ TableName: "tester" }).promise();
        getItemsPromise.then((data) => this.setState({ contactList: data.Items }));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.state.contactList[0].link.S}</div>
        );
    }
}
export default Test;
```

I am trying to render the returned value, but can't. If I set

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.contactList[0].link.S);
    return (
        <div>test</div>
    );
}
```

it works. Why is that? Why is it not working when I set it straight inline?

Comment: `this.state.contactList[0]` is `undefined` before the promise is resolved, so `this.state.contactList[0].link` will give rise to an error. You could try `<div>{this.state.contactList[0] && this.state.contactList[0].link.S}</div>` as an experiment.

Comment: @Tholle, hmm. worked. But is there a way to correctly render it?

Comment: What do you mean "correctly render it"?

Comment: You could e.g. return `null` from render until the array has been filled with your objects. `render() { if (this.state.contactList.length === 0) { return null; } return <div> ... </div>; }`

Comment: I mean `<div>{this.state.contactList[0] && this.state.contactList[0].link.S}</div>` looks weird.

Comment: you could also show some sort of 'loading' message until you get the response from the promise

Comment: @Tholle, please set as answer, I will accept.

Comment: `{this.state.contactList[0] && this.state.contactList[0].link.S}` isn't weird, that's just basic JSX [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.state.contactList[0]` is `undefined` before the promise is resolved, so `this.state.contactList[0].link` will give rise to an error.

You could e.g. return `null` from the render method until the array has been filled with your objects:

```js
class Test extends Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    if (this.state.contactList.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }

    return <div>{this.state.contactList[0].link.S}</div>;
  }
}
```